# Use Android device settings in my app

Tags: android, settings, wifi

I am on Android 2.3 and need to use the default system Wifi settings screen as part of my application. I was hoping to find a way to "wrap" it because this is part of a configuration manager app.

So if Wifi is not configured, the user cannot continue. Is there any easy way to display the Wifi settings screen with a "next >" button at the bottom?

EDIT:
This basically is NOT doable. The only option here was to "recreate" the wifi settings screen in my app, which is a royal pain, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [android.provider.Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) for a series of Intent actions you can use to launch various settings screens (e.g., ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS).

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(MainActivity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        /*
         * 3G confirm
         */
        Boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();

        /*
         * wifi confirm
         */
        Boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if(is3g){
            textView.setText("3G");
        }else if(isWifi){
            textView.setText("wifi");
        }else{
            textView.setText("nothing");
         //Activity transfer to wifi settings
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

Include following permission in Manifest.

```
<intent android:action="android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS"/>
```

You can fire following intent to so WIFI Settings screen.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: Please read the question before answering. Neither of these work for me. Neither of these meet the criteria of:
"..Wifi settings screen with a "next >" button at the bottom?"

I need to include the default wifi activity into my app, NOT redirect to it. "startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));" - all this does is start the device activity.

Ideally that screen would be inside a frame/fragment in my app so I could put a "Next >" button and/or help button at the bottom.